logback - show only errors in catalina.out
I have this file logback-spring.xml:
<configuration>

    <property name="DEV_HOME" value="./logs" />

    <appender name="FILE-AUDIT"  class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${DEV_HOME}/dana.log</file>
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <pattern>%black(%date{"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS", "Europe/Brussels"}) %highlight(%-5level) [%green(%X{sessionId})] %yellow(%logger{36}@%method\(%line\)) - %msg%n%throwable</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- rollover daily -->
            <fileNamePattern>${DEV_HOME}/archive/dana.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.gz</fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>1MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        </rollingPolicy>

    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE-AUDITSPRING"  class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${DEV_HOME}/springframework.log</file>
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <pattern>%date{"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss,SSSXXX", Europe/Brussels} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>

        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- rollover daily -->
            <fileNamePattern>${DEV_HOME}/archive/springframework.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.gz</fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>1MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        </rollingPolicy>

    </appender>

<appender name="FILE-CATALINA"  class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${DEV_HOME}/catalina.out</file>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <pattern>%black(%date{"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS", "Europe/Brussels"}) %highlight(%-5level) [%green(%X{sessionId})] %yellow(%logger{36}@%method\(%line\)) - %msg%n%throwable</pattern>
    </encoder>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- rollover daily -->
        <fileNamePattern>${DEV_HOME}/archive/catalina.out.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.gz</fileNamePattern>
        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <maxFileSize>1MB</maxFileSize>
        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
    </rollingPolicy>

</appender>

<root level="ERROR">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE-CATALINA" />
</root>

    <appender name="FILE-AUDIT-WF"  class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${DEV_HOME}/activiti.log</file>
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <pattern>%date{"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss,SSSXXX", Europe/Brussels} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>

        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- rollover daily -->
            <fileNamePattern>${DEV_HOME}/archive/activiti.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.gz</fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>1MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        </rollingPolicy>

    </appender>


    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender" >
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date{"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss,SSSXXX", Europe/Brussels} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="ERROR">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    </root>

    <root level="ERROR">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>

    <!--springProfile name="dev"-->
        <logger name="com.keuroa.em" level="error" additivity="true">
            <appender-ref ref="FILE-AUDIT" />
        </logger>
        <logger name="org.springframework" level="error" additivity="true">
            <appender-ref ref="FILE-AUDITSPRING" />
        </logger>

        <logger name="org.activiti" level="error" additivity="true">
            <appender-ref ref="FILE-AUDIT-WF" />
        </logger>
        <logger name="org.activiti5" level="error" additivity="true">
            <appender-ref ref="FILE-AUDIT-WF" />
        </logger>
    <!--/springProfile-->

    <springProfile name="prod">
        <logger name="com.keuroa.em" level="WARN" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="FILE-AUDIT" />
        </logger>
        <logger name="org.springframework" level="WARN" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="FILE-AUDITSPRING" />
        </logger>

        <logger name="org.activiti" level="WARN" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="FILE-AUDIT-WF" />
        </logger>
        <logger name="org.activiti5" level="WARN" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="FILE-AUDIT-WF" />
        </logger>
    </springProfile>



    <logger name="org.springframework.security" level="ERROR" />


</configuration>

but in {server}/logs/tomcat/catalina.out, I see
7:01:33.324 [activiti-acquire-timer-jobs] DEBUG org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.TimerJobEntityImpl.selectTimerJobsToExecute - ==>  Preparing: select * from ( select a.*, ROWNUM rnum from ( select RES.* from ACT_RU_TIMER_JOB RES where DUEDATE_ <= ? and LOCK_OWNER_ is null ) a where ROWNUM < ?) where rnum >= ? 
17:01:33.325 [activiti-acquire-timer-jobs] DEBUG org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.TimerJobEntityImpl.selectTimerJobsToExecute - ==> Parameters: 2024-11-07 17:01:33.324(Timestamp), 2(Integer), 1(Integer)
17:01:33.326 [activiti-acquire-timer-jobs] DEBUG org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.TimerJobEntityImpl.selectTimerJobsToExecute - <==      Total: 0
17:01:33.326 [activiti-acquire-timer-jobs] DEBUG org.activiti.engine.impl.db.DbSqlSession - Flushing dbSqlSession
17:01:33.326 [activiti-acquire-timer-jobs] DEBUG org.activiti.engine.impl.db.DbSqlSession - flush summary: 0 insert, 0 update, 0 delete.
17:01:33.326 [activiti-acquire-timer-jobs] DEBUG org.activiti.engine.impl.db.DbSqlSession - now executing flush...
17:01:33.326 [activiti-acquire-timer-jobs] DEBUG org.apache.ibatis.transaction.managed.ManagedTransaction - Closing JDBC Connection [Transaction-aware proxy for target Connection [ProxyConnection[PooledConnection[oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@65a0287e]]]]
17:01:33.326 [activiti-acquire-timer-jobs] DEBUG org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Initiating transaction commit
17:01:33.326 [activiti-acquire-timer-jobs] DEBUG org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Committing JPA transaction on EntityManager [org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl@7591a8b2]
17:01:33.326 [activiti-acquire-timer-jobs] DEBUG org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Closing JPA EntityManager [org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl@7591a8b2] after transaction
17:01:33.326 [activiti-acquire-timer-jobs] DEBUG org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.LogInterceptor - --- AcquireTimerJobsCmd finished --------------------------------------------------------
17:01:33.326 [activiti-acquire-timer-jobs] DEBUG org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.LogInterceptor - 


it looks as if your config file is completely ignored and another one is used instead, just look at the format of the timestamps.

How is your setup configured in general? Do you run Tomcat from a fat jar of Spring Boot? Do you use Spring Boot at all?

If you are desperate you might want to turn on Java's verbose logging of classloading as the configuration file is most likely loaded through a classloader, with: java -verbose:class yourapplication.jar or similar

Use <configuration debug='true'> to see what logback is doing.

There are multiple root definitions and a reference to a "CONSOLE" appender that is not defined.
In the logback-spring.xml example you share there are multiple root definitions (FILE-CATALINA, CONSOLE, STDOUT).
Also, apparently there is a reference to a "CONSOLE" appender that is not defined.
Try:

Unifying root config in only one declaration.
Deleting the reference to "CONSOLE" appender that is not defined.
Adding Activity config.

As a reference, you could base it on something like the following:
<configuration>
    <property name="DEV_HOME" value="./logs" />

    <!-- ... others appenders ... -->

    <!-- only one root config -->
    <root level="ERROR">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE-CATALINA" />
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>

    <!--  Activiti Config-->
    <logger name="org.activiti" level="ERROR" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE-AUDIT-WF" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE-CATALINA" />
    </logger>
    
    <logger name="org.activiti.engine" level="ERROR" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE-AUDIT-WF" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE-CATALINA" />
    </logger>

    <!-- ... other configs ... -->
</configuration>


Ensure it's functioning as expected:

**Duplicate <root> Elements:** You have multiple <root level="ERROR"> elements, each with a different appender (FILE-CATALINA, CONSOLE, STDOUT). Only one <root> element is allowed per configuration, as it sets the default logging level and output for all loggers that don't have explicit configurations. Merge these into a single <root> element:



  <root level="ERROR">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE-CATALINA" />
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
**Console Appender Issue:** There is an attempt to reference a CONSOLE appender, but it’s not defined in your configuration. You only have an appender named STDOUT. If you want the CONSOLE appender, rename STDOUT to CONSOLE or add an appender named CONSOLE.

**File Paths and Rotation:** Each RollingFileAppender should specify a different filename and file path to avoid conflicts. Ensure ${DEV_HOME}/logs exists and is writable by the application.

**Active Profile Check:** Your <springProfile name="dev"> and <springProfile name="prod"> blocks are currently commented out. For environment-specific configurations to take effect, uncomment these sections.


Full content found on https://admirable-smakager-729141.netlify.app/post/9

